# In Sharepoint Search, It currently shows all the columns with the word and so on.I want to restrict.How to do this?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, managed-property, sharepoint-search, crawled-property

I created managed property. It works fine. But it is bringing many results also shows similar words. I want to restrict it to "one word" not likely search
and I want it to search just one column.

For example if i got this managed property like this >> `Csearch:Sharepoint`

I only want to see the results in the `CSearch` column that contain only one-to-one `"Sharepoint"` word.

How can i do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using KQL, you can construct queries that use property restrictions to narrow the focus of the query to match only results based on a specified condition.

You can search with "managed property:value" to restrict search results from special column.

Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference